# Find two cycles of length $r$ and $s$ such that the order of their product is not $\operatorname{lcm}(r,s)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to find two cycles of length $r$ and $s$ such that the order of their product is not $\operatorname{lcm}(r,s)$.

MY try: Take $ \pi = (123)$ and $\sigma = (12) $.
Then, $ \pi \sigma = (123)(12) = (13) \implies o( \pi \sigma ) = 2 $.

Also, I want to find a permutation of order $2$ that is not a transposition:

My try: $\sigma = (23)(14) $

IS this correct?

Comment: Both are correct (assuming, in the first part, that you evaluate compositions from right to left).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in both instances. A (slightly) simpler example for the first one is the pair $\pi = (1\ 2)$ and $\sigma = (1\ 2)$ in $S_n$, $n \geq 2$, both of which have order $2$ but $\pi\sigma = e$ has order $1 \neq 2 = \operatorname{lcm}\{2, 2\}$.